# I am using monodevelop and I am getting a "framework mono/.NET 4.0 not installed" error when I try to build

Tags: mono, monodevelop

The fun part is, I do have .NET 4.0 installed, as well as all GTK#. I thought maybe I installed it in the wrong order or something ridiculous, so I uninstalled and re-installed everything. I even tried installing plain old mono, and then installing monodevelop, but I still get that same error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIRC MonoDevelop 2.4 had a bug that prevented it targeting the final released version of .NET 4.0. The fix should be in MonoDevelop 2.4.1.

As a workaround, assuming you installed Mono 2.8 (which has 4.0 support), you can change your target runtime to Mono instead of .NET. Either

- Change the default using the *Tools -> Options* menu, then the *.NET Runtimes* panel

or

- Change the target of the current project using the *Project->Target Runtime* menu.

Comment: I found a great shell script to install latest mono and monodevelop here: http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2011/03/monodevelop-2-4-and-2-6-beta-install-script-for-ubuntu-fedora/

Comment: Thank you so much! Spent hours trying to figure out why MonoDevelop would only target MS .NET when I explicitly set Mono as a build target. Turned out I didn't add it as another .NET Runtime in the Tools -> Options.

Answer (score 3):

you could easily change the framework under which tyour application is running to allow MonoDevelop build your's successfully by doing the following:

- open menu "Project"
- choose Application options
- from "General" tab, change the "Target framework" to be "Mono / .NET x"